# Is there a way of using WCF and .NET Remoting at the same time?

Tags: wcf, remoting, wcf-binding

Due to deployment restrictions, we can't deploy WCF on the client-side (yet) but would like to use it on the server-side.

I am interested to know if it is possible to use WCF on the server but consume it with .NET remoting on the client side. I don't have any problems with using specific bindings, transfers or protocols on the server side to make this happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely possible - [here is a good place to start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730857(VS.80).aspx).